# Change weight of font while maintaining local formatting in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

I have a large block of text that is set to "book" with local italics throughout being set to "book italic."

I'd like to increase the weight of the whole works: with the stuff currently set at "book" changed to "medium," and the stuff set to "book italic" set to "medium italic."

I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve going through the text by hand and individually selecting all of the italicized bits. Is there a way that I can just highlight the whole works and tell InDesign to change the "base" bits to "medium" and the italicized bits to "medium italic?"

Comment: @Scott I guess what I'm asking is how would one go about altering the styles to accomplish what I'm after...

Answer (score 2):

I'd copy and paste the block of text into a new document (so you don't mess with any of the other text in your original document).

Then use `Find Font` to change your book and italic text to your new desired weights.

Copy and paste the corrected text back into your original document.

Answer (score 1):

Backup your document.

Use find/change with the text tab (depending on what you want to do, the GREP tab may be a better choice)

Find What > wildcard "any character" (`^?`)

Find format: choose the old typeface in the basic character formats section (list is limited to those already used in the document).
Change format: choose the new typeface

"find then change" will change character.
"change all" will change everything

Note that your text will reflow after you change the typeface, so don't forget to check your document from the top down.